# Web pack build fails with Non-Zero Exit Code detected

Tags: webpack, terser-webpack-plugin

|  | 228 ms (parallelism 80.7) build modules > ./app/components/TabButton/A.js

|  | 228 ms (parallelism 80.7) build modules > ./app/components/TabButton/Wrapper.js

**| 129273 ms build modules > 1329 x javascript/auto with ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 138642 ms build modules**

- 1180 hidden lines

Webpack build failing by, the above bolded lines showing in red.

Don't have any idea what was the error

Any suggestions?

Thanks